# Remove right side of box shadow

Tags: html, css

I have found lots of posts similar to what I am asking and have been working away at this for hours and finally decided I should probably seek some exterior advice :).

I am trying to shadow 3 sides of an div using box-shadow I want the right side to be shadowless but cannot figure it out there are lots of posts on how to un-shadow the top but after countless efforts i could not even apply this.

Comment: Please, create a sample in http://jsfiddle.net/ or else post your code what you have tried

Comment: I know this is an oldie, but do you know the size of the div to which the box-shadow is applied? i.e. does the div have a set size or is it flexible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have 2 options:

1) Set your shadow's horizontal alignment to the left (negative values).

```
box-shadow: -30px 0px 10px 10px #888888;
```

Although this way you won't have the same shadow size in the top and bottom.

2) Use a div inside a div and apply shadow to each one.

```
.div1
{
    box-shadow: -30px 10px 20px 10px #888888;
}
.div2
{
    box-shadow: -30px -10px 20px 10px #888888;
}
```

Then you'll have to ajust the size for the one you want.

Here, have a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwgKF/19/

Comment: Hey I just answered you... And it is alright... But you didn't accept it... So do it maybe! :P

Comment: clip-path worked for me

Answer (score 88):

### Update:

`clip-path` is now (2020) supported in all major browsers.

---

### Original Answer:

If you're willing to use experimental technology with only [partial support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path), you could use the [`clip path` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

This will provide you with exactly the effect I believe you are after: a normal box shadow on the top, left and bottom edges and clean cut-off on the right edge. A lot of other SO solutions to this issue result in shadows that "dissipate" as they near the edge that is to have no shadow.

In your case you would use clip-path: inset(px px px px); where the pixel values are calculated from the edge in question (see below).

```
#container {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(-5px 0px -5px -5px);
    clip-path: inset(-5px 0px -5px -5px);
}
```

This will clip the div in question at:

- 5 pixels above the top edge (to include the shadow)
- 0 pixels from the right edge (to hide the shadow)
- 5 pixels below the bottom edge (to include the shadow)
- 5 pixels outside of the left edge (to include the shadow)

Note that no commas are required between pixel values.

The size of the div can be flexible.

Comment: I'll stress, that this is the best, IMHO, way to do it. Now (2019) all major browsers support `clip-path` except Edge/IE, but now when Chromium based Edge is out - I think that becomes none of a concern.

Comment: You can make use of the clip-path method to create an effect that merges two elements together to have a seamless shadow between the two. Use a width calc() to position two elements next to each other. Then add the box-shadow to both elements, followed by the clip-path on only one of them. Set the z-index of the clip-path'd element to be higher than the non-clip-path'd element. [Here's an example. The horizontal part is one element and the vertical part is a separate element.](https://i.imgur.com/q0lwCQl.png)

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Still best to use the `-webkit` prefix though, some modern browsers still depend on it, as in 2023 it's nearly +5% support, which makes clip-path 95% supported — safe to use.

Comment: @Max, agreed. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:after` pseudo element : http://jsfiddle.net/romiguelangel/YCh6F/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li class="hello"><a href="#">item with after element</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px gray
}

.hello:after{
    display: block;
    background-color: #f3f5f6;
    width: 20px;
    height: 38px;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px
}
```

Answer (score -4):

try using this example hasn't right side border:

**[JsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ikeyiv/3/watch)**

Comment: Please give more details in your answer instead of just a JsBin link.

Answer (score -6):

NONE of the above responses will work.

I am assuming you are using bootstrap or a library that has box-shadow in the default buttons. Here is the solution:

```
.your-btn-class {
    box-shadow: none /* Removes the default box-shadow */
    box-shadow: -0.1rem 0 0 0.2rem rgba(134, 142, 150, 0.5); /* Add your own      */
}
```

(if you don't remove the initial box-shadow, then when you tried to remove the offset from the right, the left side will be double the size of the top and bottom. That's why you have to remove it. If you are not sure what the default colors of the box-shadow of the library you are using. Just go to the source code and find-out, not hard at all)

If you just need to add box-shadow to you button or input on all side except the right do:

```
.your-btn-class {
     box-shadow: -0.1rem 0 0 0.2rem rgba(134, 142, 150, 0.5);
}
```